# Getting to remote server from Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: dreamweaver

All of a sudden, I'm getting the following message in the area where
my remote files used to be listed:

"To see the files in your repository you must define its Version
Control settings."

This is happening for multiple sites and the Version Control setting
is set to none (and it always has been).

I had another Dreamweaver author, try it on her system and she got to the remote server just fine. When I logged on to her system I got the same problem, but this time it said "FTP error...password problem..."--she's on Windows 7--I'm on XP. Our company does not support "version control." I can't find any "SVNs" lieing around either.

Comment: This is more of a superuser.com question I think, voting to migrate there. But FWIW, are you sure you are in the correct tab? I'm not familiar with Dreamweaver, but this sounds like a "repositories" view more than a "remote files" one

Comment: Are you sure you're not in the 'Repository View' in the Files tab? When I switch to it from 'Local View', I get the same message.

Comment: Thank you Curt! Yes, somehow it had "moved" to repository. Once I picked the remote icon, I had to remap from the "show" pulldown menu--then it came back. Thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will see this message when you are in the 'Repository View' and you haven't set up version control. You can check this in the FILES tab/window. If you don't see it press F8 or select Window/Files. Switch from Repository view to Local View, Test Sever, or Remote Server as appropriate.